# Both Datasource and DatasourceID are defined on GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I get the above error in my C#/SQL/ASP.NET app because I have a datasource defined both in the ASPX file and the ASPX.CS file.  But I want the Gridview to have selectable rows.  So if I comment out the ASPX.CS datasource I get the above error but if I comment out the ASPX datasource I get the Gridview output but it is not selectable.  How do I code this successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You should only be specifying one or the other.  If you want to give the data object directly to the grid, set the DataSource to be that object.

Otherwise, set the DataSourceID to the ID of the datasource that you want to be binding to, and let it do it's thing.

Selectable rows shouldn't have anything to do with where the data is coming from.  You can select a row by setting the SelectedRow property.  Making them selectable in the UI is a whole different topic.

Comment: I looked at the SelectedRow property definition, but I don't see how I can use this to make the rows selectable.  Is there a way to make the rows selectable in the GridView from the ASPX.CS file instead?

Comment: As I said, it's a whole different topic than your initial question.  I would suggest looking for some walkthroughs of the GridView control and using the SelectCommand, and then checking out something like http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View9FC28EE6-ACB0-4F51-BFE4-38B0B10134D5.htm

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to just set the [DataSourceID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.databoundcontrol.datasourceid.aspx) from the markup, and set [AutoGenerateSelectButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogenerateselectbutton.aspx) to true in your markup as well.  Your question makes it sound like this is the behavior you are looking for.  If you'd rather generate your own select buttons, you should look into either [CommandFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandfield.aspx), or just adding your own buttons with a [CommandName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandname.aspx) of "Select".

Comment: What I tried: 
1. set the DataSource in the ASPX file to the hard-coded datasource value in the ASPX file.
2. Checked Enable selection in the ASPX file.
3. Commented out the datasource in the ASPX.CS file

Result: 
"Unable to open the physical file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks_Data.mdf". Operating system error 32: "32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)".

Is this what you meant for me to do?

Comment: Generally, in the aspx, you'll use the DataSourceID and point it to a DataSource control (SqlDataSource in your case).  It sounds like you have your datasource setup wrong.  Try using a SqlDataSource in the markup, give it a correct connection string, and point it at the query that you want to use.

Comment: Thanks Scott, but unfortunately now my database connection is closed in VS Server Explorer.  There is a red "X" next to it.  So I restarted my computer but this connection was still closed.  Then I checked Services and all the SQL services were started.  And I verified this by opening SSMS and the AdventureWorks database.  SO the problem is just that I can't open the MDF file for this DB from VS.